# C# - Lost in Regex - Matching groups on different machines

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I've thought I knew how to write basic regex. On my x64 pc in VS2008, C#, I'm writing the following regex:

```
private static readonly Regex TagRegex = new Regex(@"\{QTable\((?<key>(.*?))#(?<query>(.*?))#(?<columns>(.*?))#(?<heading>(.*?))#(?<tbl>(.*?))#(?<headers>(.*?))#(?<row>(.*?))\)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

This regex should find all entries like:

```
{QTable(XXX#YYY#ZZZ#111#222#333#444)}
```

Enabling me to use named groups and pick each value key,query etc...
And in my unit test + debug mode it works, even on my own 5.1 IIS (x86) where I deploy the app it works.
However when I deploy on the production server it doesn't, it throws a ney not present in dictionary when trying to access the named groups.

Comment: In `(.*?)`, why `?` is needed?

Comment: @Vlad: That makes the `.*` non-greedy -- so it won't just blindly match everything it can, even if doing so will cause the later matches to fail.

Comment: I'd write ([^#]*) instead ... the # are markers, and he wants to match until the next marker

Comment: Do you know what it matched? Do you know the input string? (=Can you debug or did you log?)

Comment: Hi guys,found the error. I had forgotten to check a dictionary elsewhere but in the same scope and almost hidden. My bad. Sorry for the inconviniense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Of course a completely unrelated place. Nothing wrong with the regex :).
Sorry for any inconvenience.